# Does Firebase support batch operations in REST API?

Tags: rest, firebase

I need batch **DELETE**, **POST** operations when using Firebase.
Does it support **batch operations** in REST API?

Comment: No. https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/

Comment: That leaves the question **why** you need this? You can already repeatedly call the individual operations. What would be different from your perspective when you'd be able to call them in a batch?

Comment: You seem to have asked the same here: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/p6vd1_u_SHk

Comment: I also need this functionality from a scaling perspective. I don't want to send 20 POST requests when I could submit 20 items in one. Also, if you want the order to be preserved you would want to do a single batch POST instead of hoping the network latency works in your favor with 20 requests.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest "batch" operation in Firebase would be to move up one level in the tree and either do a PATCH or DELETE op.

Consider the following data structure:

```
/foo/bar
/foo/baz
/foo/bap
/foo/bam
```

If I want to remove `bar` and `baz`, I could do the following:

```
curl -X PATCH https://<instance>.firebaseio.com/<PATH>.json -d '{"bar": null, "baz": null}'
```