# How batch update firebase database using REST API?

Tags: rest, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I need to update all values from a database stored in a Firebase database.

The value I must update is a flag to mark the data as "parsed" already. This way our system will not parse duplicate data.

It must be done by REST API.

Comment: Have you read the doc reference already? https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26519930/does-firebase-support-batch-operations-in-rest-api

Comment: @JoshuaChan it's a 4 years old question. Firebase evolves a lot since then.

Comment: *firebaser here* The Firebase platform has definitely evolved. But that database operation still work exactly the same. Give it a spin, and post back if you have problems.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen Is it intended that you can patch grandchildren? Because in my experiment just now, grandchildren siblings were deleted when I set a new grandchild.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The current latest docs at https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database/ still exposes the same api endpoint with the same concept.

Just send a HTTP PATCH at the highest possible parent node that covers all the data you want to update?

Comment: This didn't work for me. For grandchildren, the siblings were overwritten when I tried to set a key.